# Code Golf: Zigzag pattern scanning

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The Challenge

The shortest code by character count that takes a single input integer `N` (N >= 3) and returns an array of indices that when iterated would traverse an `N`x`N` matrix according to the JPEG "zigzag" scan pattern. The following is an example traversal over an 8x8 matrix<sup>[src](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg)</sup>:

[image: zigzag layout pattern]

#### Examples

(The middle matrix is not part of the input or output, just a representation of the NxN matrix the input represents.)

```
                1 2 3
(Input) 3  -->  4 5 6  -->  1 2 4 7 5 3 6 8 9 (Output)
                7 8 9

                1  2  3  4
(Input) 4  -->  5  6  7  8  -->  1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 10 13 14 11 8 12 15 16 (Output)
                9 10 11 12
               13 14 15 16
```

#### Notes

- The resulting array's base should be appropriate for your language (e.g., Matlab arrays are 1-based, C++ arrays are 0-based).
- This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939).

### Bonus

Extend your answer to take two inputs `N` and `M` (N, M >=3) and perform the same scan over an `N`x`M` matrix. (In this case `N` would be the number of columns and `M` the number of rows.)

#### Bonus Examples

```
                  1  2  3  4
(Input) 4 3  -->  5  6  7  8  -->  1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 10 11 8 12 (Output)
                  9 10 11 12

                   1  2  3
(Input) 3 4  -->   4  5  6  -->  1 2 4 7 5 3 6 8 10 11 9 12 (Output)
                   7  8  9
                  10 11 12
```

Comment: I'll start the J pool with... under 7 characters.

Comment: @Mark: The best I have so far is 15. I'm pretty sure 7 isn't possible for this question, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: why is it i spend a day of coding then i spend 3 more hours doing code golf? =P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### J, 13 <s>15</s> characters

```
;<@|.`</.i.2$
```

Usage:

```
   ;<@|.`</.i.2$  3
0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 8

   ;<@|.`</.i.2$  4
0 1 4 8 5 2 3 6 9 12 13 10 7 11 14 15
```

### Explanation

(`NB.` is J's comment indicator)

```
;         NB. Link together...
<@|.`<    NB. ... 'take the reverse of' and 'take normally'
/.        NB. ... applied to alternating diagonals of...
i.        NB. ... successive integers starting at 0 and counting up to fill an array with dimensions of...
2$        NB. ... the input extended cyclically to a list of length two.
```

### J, bonus, 13 characters

```
;<@|.`</.i.|.
```

Usage:

```
   ;<@|.`</.i.|. 3 4
0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 9 10 8 11

   ;<@|.`</.i.|. 9 6
0 1 9 18 10 2 3 11 19 27 36 28 20 12 4 5 13 21 29 37 45 46 38 30 22 14 6 7 15 23 31 39 47 48 40 32 24 16 8 17 25 33 41 49 50 42 34 26 35 43 51 52 44 53
```

Comment: I like how it takes two characters to do 'applied to alternating diagonals of'.

Comment: yea the 'alternating diagonal' built-in is what makes this possible. im workin on a goflscript solution which doesnt use that.. will see how short it can be

Answer (score 11):

## Python, 92, <s>95</s>, <s>110</s>, <s>111</s>, <s>114</s>, <s>120</s>, <s>122</s>, <s>162</s>, <s>164</s> chars

```
N=input()
for a in sorted((p%N+p/N,(p%N,p/N)[(p%N-p/N)%2],p)for p in range(N*N)):print a[2],
```

Testing:

```
$ echo 3 | python ./code-golf.py 
0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 8

$ echo 4 | python ./code-golf.py 
0 1 4 8 5 2 3 6 9 12 13 10 7 11 14 15
```

This solution easily generalizes for `N`x`M` boards: tweak the input processing and replace `N*N` with `N*M`:

```
N,M=map(int,raw_input().split())
for a in sorted((p%N+p/N,(p%N,p/N)[(p%N-p/N)%2],p)for p in range(N*M)):print a[2],
```

I suspect there's some easier/shorter way to read two numbers.

Testing:

```
$ echo 4 3 | python ./code-golf.py 
0 1 4 8 5 2 3 6 9 10 7 11
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python syntax, but how does this print the numbers separated by a space?

Comment: @Adam the comma does that, also "A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma"

Comment: You can use 'split()' rather than 'replace()'

Comment: @David: No he can't. He'll be left with an array of two strings. He needs an array of two ints, so that's why he's using eval + replace. You could just use split and then cast each array element to an int, but I think that'll end up using more characters.

Comment: @wallacoloo: how about `N,M=input()` (python 2.x)?

Comment: @doublep: Well yeah but nowhere is postulated the input should be in format '4\s+3'. Based on that i think any reasonable input requirement is ok - in this case '4,\s*3'. Why should we be biased towards Google Code Jam or C input style? Other languages (Python, Basic, ...) like CSVs better ;-)
ps. example of imho unreasonable requirement - 'encode m and n by interlacing the bits and input that, e.g. for 4 (0b100) and 3 (0b011) type 37 (0b100101)

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 69 <strike>89</strike> chars

```
n=gets.to_i
puts (0...n*n).sort_by{|p|[t=p%n+p/n,[p%n,p/n][t%2]]}*' '
```

### 89 chars

```
n=gets.to_i
puts (0...n*n).map{|p|[t=p%n+p/n,[p%n,p/n][t%2],p]}.sort.map{|i|i[2]}.join' '
```

Run

```
> zigzag.rb
3
0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 8

> zigzag.rb
4
0 1 4 8 5 2 3 6 9 12 13 10 7 11 14 15
```

Credits to doublep for the sort method.

Comment: `n=eval *$<;p (0...n*n).sort_by{|p|[t=p%n+p/n,[p%n,p/n][t%2]]}`
61

Comment: @matyr: `p` prints `[0, 1, 3,...]` instead of `0 1 3...`.

Comment: @matyr, thanks for that. made it 69. eval *$< didn't work on my system.

Comment: @Sebastian "an array of indices" doesn't indicate space-separated.

@Adam `puts ` -> `$><<`.

Answer (score 5):

## F#, 126 chars

```
let n=stdin.ReadLine()|>int
for i=0 to 2*n do for j in[id;List.rev].[i%2][0..i]do if i-j<n&&j<n then(i-j)*n+j|>printf"%d "
```

Examples:

```
$ echo 3 | fsi --exec Program.fsx
0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 8

$ echo 4 | fsi --exec Program.fsx
0 1 4 8 5 2 3 6 9 12 13 10 7 11 14 15
```

Comment: `[x;y].[i%2]` rather than `if i%2=0 then x else y` - nice, gotta remember that one - props to @doublep

Comment: Oooh, that's a nice trick. I think that one might work in PowerShell as well.

Answer (score 4):

## Golfscript, 26/30 <s>32/36</s> <s>45</s> <s>59</s> characters

Shortest non-J solution so far:

Updated sort (don't tell the others!) - 30 chars:

```
 ~:1.*,{..1/\1%+.2%.+(@*]}$' '* #solution 1
#~:\.*,{.\/1$\%+.1&@.~if]}$' '* #solution 2
#~\:1*,{..1/\1%+.2%.+(@*]}$' '* #(bonus)
#~\:\*,{.\/1$\%+.1&@.~if]}$' '* #(bonus)
```

---

Straight implementation - 36 chars:

```
 ~:@.*,{[.@%:|\@/:^+|^- 2%^|if]}$' '*
#~\:@*,{[.@%:|\@/:^+|^- 2%^|if]}$' '* #(bonus)
```

If you can provide output as "013642578" instead of "0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 8", then you can remove the last 4 characters.

Credit to doublep for the sorting technique.

---

Explanation:

```
~\:@*        #read input, store first number into @, multiply the two
,            #put range(@^2) on the stack
{...}$       #sort array using the key in ...
" "*         #join array w/ spaces
```

and for the key:

```
[            #put into an array whatever is left on the stack until ]
.@%:|        #store @%n on the stack, also save it as |
\@/:^        #store @/n on the stack, also save it as ^
+            #add them together. this remains on the stack.
|^- 2%^|if   #if (| - ^) % 2 == 1, then put ^ on stack, else put | on stack.
]            #collect them into an array
```

Comment: @Nabb: you sure the updated sort works? i tried it but it gives different output

Comment: output is exactly the same for both the square and bonus problems for the values I tested

Comment: Not familiar with Golfscript, but `(a+b)%2` is equal to `(a-b)%2`. You might be able to %2 the sum of `|` and `^` if it helps saving some characters.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 101/116 chars

Its basically a condensed version of the same answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939/matrix-zigzag-reordering/3025478#3025478), to be run directly on the command prompt:

```
N=input('');i=fliplr(spdiags(fliplr(reshape(1:N*N,N,N)')));i(:,1:2:end)=flipud(i(:,1:2:end));i(i~=0)'
```

and an extended one that read two values from the user:

```
S=str2num(input('','s'));i=fliplr(spdiags(fliplr(reshape(1:prod(S),S)')));i(:,1:2:end)=flipud(i(:,1:2:end));i(i~=0)'
```

Testing:

```
3
ans =
     1     2     4     7     5     3     6     8     9
```

and

```
4 3
ans =
     1     2     5     9     6     3     4     7    10    11     8    12
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 137 <s>130</s> <s>138</s> characters

```
n=gets.to_i
def g(a,b,r,t,s);x=[s*r]*t;t==r ?[a,x,a]:[a,x,g(b,a,r,t+1,-s),x,a];end
q=0;puts ([1]+g(1,n,n-1,1,1)).flatten.map{|s|q+=s}*' '

$ zz.rb
3
1 2 4 7 5 3 6 8 9

$ zz.rb
4
1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 10 13 14 11 8 12 15 16
```

Comment: You should use `puts [array]*' '` to match the output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

## C89 (280 bytes)

I guess this can still be optimized - I use four arrays to store the possible movement
vectors when hitting a wall. I guess it can be done, saving some chars at the definition, but I think it will cost more to implement the logic further down. Anyway, here you go:

```
t,l,b,r,i,v,n;main(int c,char**a){n=atoi(*++a);b=n%2;int T[]={n-1,1},L[]={1-n,n}
,B[]={1-n,1},R[]={n-1,n};for(c=n*n;c--;){printf("%d%c",i,c?32:10);if(i>=n*(n-1))
v=B[b=!b];else if(i%n>n-2){if(!(n%2)&&i<n)goto g;v=R[r=!r];}else if(i<n)g:v=T[t=
!t];else if(!(i%n))v=L[l=!l];i+=v;}}
```

compiles with a few warnings, but as far as I know it is portable C89. I'm actually not sure
whether my algorithm is clever at all, maybe you can get way shorter with a better one
(haven't taken the time to understand the other solutions yet).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell 117 characters

```
i s=concatMap(\q->d q++(reverse.d$q+1))[0,2..s+s]
 where d r=[x+s*(r-x)|x<-[0..r],x<s&&(r-x)<s]
main=readLn>>=print.i
```

Runs:

```
$ echo 3 | ./Diagonals 
[0,1,3,6,4,2,5,7,8]

$ echo 4 | ./Diagonals 
[0,1,4,8,5,2,3,6,9,12,13,10,7,11,14,15]
```

The rectangular variant is a little longer, at 120 characters:

```
j(w,h)=concatMap(\q->d q++(reverse.d$q+1))[0,2..w+h]
 where d r=[x+w*(r-x)|x<-[0..r],x<w&&(r-x)<h]
main=readLn>>=print.j
```

Input here requires a tuple:

```
$ echo '(4,3)' | ./Diagonals 
[0,1,4,8,5,2,3,6,9,10,7,11]

$ echo '(3,4)' | ./Diagonals 
[0,1,3,6,4,2,5,7,9,10,8,11]
```

Answers are all 0-based, and returned as lists (natural forms for Haskell).

Answer (score 0):

Perl 102 characters

```
<>=~/ /;print map{$_%1e6," "}sort map{($x=($%=$_%$`)+($/=int$_/$`))*1e9+($x%2?$/:$%)*1e6+$_}0..$'*$`-1
```

usage :

```
echo 3 4 | perl zigzag.pl
0 1 3 6 4 2 5 7 9 10 8 11
```