# transforming a matrix into a vector along its diagonals

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, transform

im not not a programmer, i just need to solve something numerically in matlab.
i need a function to make the following transformation for any square matrix:

from

```
row 1: 1 2 3 
row 2: 4 5 6
row 3: 7 8 9
```

to

```
1 4 2 7 5 3 8 6 9
```

ie write the matrix in a vector along its diagonals from left to top right.
any ideas please?

---

i really need a little more help though:

say the matrix that we have transformed into the vector, has entries denoted by M(i,j), where i are rows and j columns. now i need to be able to find out from a position in the vector, the original position in the matrix, i.e say if its 3rd entry in the vector, i need a function that would give me i=1 j=2. any ideas please? im really stuck on this:( thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is quite similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939/matrix-zigzag-reordering) on traversing the matrix in a zigzag order. With slight modification we get:

```
A = rand(3);                        %# input matrix

ind = reshape(1:numel(A), size(A)); %# indices of elements
ind = spdiags(fliplr(ind));         %# get the anti-diagonals
ind = ind(end:-1:1);                %# reverse order
ind = ind(ind~=0);                  %# keep non-zero indices
B = A(ind);                         %# get elements in desired order
```

using the [SPDIAGS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html) function. The advantage of this is that it works for any arbitrary matrix size (not just square matrices). Example:

```
A =
      0.75127      0.69908      0.54722      0.25751
       0.2551       0.8909      0.13862      0.84072
      0.50596      0.95929      0.14929      0.25428
B =
  Columns 1 through 6
      0.75127       0.2551      0.69908      0.50596       0.8909      0.54722
  Columns 7 through 12
      0.95929      0.13862      0.25751      0.14929      0.84072      0.25428
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do this.

```
%# n is the number of rows (or cols) of the square array
n = 3;
array = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]; %# this is the array we'll reorder

%# create list of indices that allow us
%# to read the array in the proper order
hh = hankel(1:n,n:(2*n-1)); %# creates a matrix with numbered antidiagonals
[dummy,sortIdx] = sort(hh(:)); %# sortIdx contains the new order

%# reorder the array
array(sortIdx)

ans =
     1     4     2     7     5     3     8     6     9
```

Comment: The call to BSXFUN is unnecessary. You can just do `sort(hh(:))` to get the index vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your matrix to a vector using the function [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) to generate indices into the matrix. Here's a shortened version of [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440641/transforming-a-matrix-into-a-vector-along-its-diagonals/3440808#3440808), using `M` as your sample matrix given above:

```
N = size(M,1);
A = hankel(1:N,N:(2*N-1));
[junk,sortIndex] = sort(A(:));
```

Now, you can use `sortIndex` to change your matrix `M` to a vector `vec` like so:

```
vec = M(sortIndex);
```

And if you want to get the row and column indices (`rIndex` and `cIndex`) into your original matrix that correspond to the values in `vec`, you can use the function [IND2SUB](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[rIndex,cIndex] = ind2sub(N,sortIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
d = size(A,1);
X=[];
for n = 1:2*size(A,1) - 1
    j = min(n,d); i = (n+1)-(j);
    X = cat(2,X,diag(flipud(A(i:j,i:j)))');
end

X
X =
     1     4     2     7     5     3     8     6     9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the diagonals in this way:

```
for i = -2:2
    diag(flipud(a), i)
end
```

I don't know whether this is the optimal way to concatenate the diagonals:

```
d = []
for i = -2:2
    d = vertcat(d, diag(flipud(a), i))
end
```

(I tested it in octave, not in matlab)