# How can I get counterdiagonals of a matrix and concatenate them?

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation, diagonal

### Short Version

How can I do `concatMap` in MATLAB? I'm trying to build a single vector from a series of smaller, differently sized vectors. I know I can do:

```
result = [];
for i=1:N
    result = [result nextPart(i)];
end
```

but that has a serious speed impact and there must be a smarter way to do `concatMap`.

---

### Long Version

I'm trying to write a MATLAB function that returns the counterdiagonals of a block. For example, if you have the block:

```
1 2 4
3 5 7
6 8 9
```

then `counterDiagonals(block)` should return `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`.

I have a function that will find a single counter diagonal of a block. i.e. `counterDiagonal(x, 3)` will return `[4 5 6]`.

Therefore, `counterDiagonals` should be as simple as `concatMap counterDiagonal(x, i) (1:N)` where `N` is `(2*length(block)-1)`. How can I do this in MATLAB in an efficient way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [transforming a matrix into a vector along its diagonals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440641/transforming-a-matrix-into-a-vector-along-its-diagonals)

Comment: @gnovice: as was recently discussed by Jeff Atwood, having multiple variations of the same question isn't so bad after all :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @Amro: True. I saw that post, and I agree some amount of duplication is unavoidable and maybe even beneficial. But the way I interpreted it was that Jeff still encouraged closing and potentially merging some, but not *deleting* them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want to do can be accomplished using the functions [ROT90](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rot90.html) and [SPDIAGS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html):

```
A = [1 2 4; 3 5 7; 6 8 9];  %# Sample matrix
result = rot90(A);          %# Rotate the matrix counter-clockwise
result = spdiags(result);   %# Find all the diagonals
result = result(result ~= 0).';  %'# Remove zero padding and format the results
                                  %#   into a row vector
```

And you should end up with `result = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`.

**EDIT:** As Amro mentions in a comment, the above code assumes that there are no zeroes in the original matrix `A`. If there are zeroes in the original matrix, one solution is to replace them with a non-zero flag value that you know doesn't appear in the original matrix (like, for example, [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html)), run the above code, then replace the flag values in the result:

```
A = [0 2 4; 3 0 7; 6 8 0];  %# Sample matrix
result = rot90(A);          %# Rotate the matrix counter-clockwise
result(result == 0) = nan;  %# Replace zeroes with NaN
result = spdiags(result);   %# Find all the diagonals
result = result(result ~= 0).';  %'# Remove zero padding and format the results
                                  %#   into a row vector
result(isnan(result)) = 0;  %# Put the original zeroes back
```

Comment: +1 for using `rot90` - I'd have used `fliplr` and have suffered.

Comment: you will get incorrect results if the original matrix contained zeros. See my post below.

Comment: @Amro: That's correct, but I was just going on the sample matrix provided.

Comment: using `NaN`'s is probably easier than my solution +1

Answer (score 4):

One problem with the accepted answer: if the matrix `A` had zeros, they will be incorrectly removed from the result.. Instead you should work on the indices of the elements:

```
A = [0 2 4; 3 5 7; 6 8 9];               %# Sample matrix (contains zeros)

ind = reshape(1:numel(A), size(A));      %# indices of elements
ind = fliplr( spdiags( fliplr(ind) ) );  %# get the anti-diagonals (or use ROT90)
ind(ind==0) = [];                        %# keep non-zero indices
result = A(ind);                         %# get elements in desired order
```

This is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440641/transforming-a-matrix-into-a-vector-along-its-diagonals/3443860#3443860) I gave in a previous question (the difference was that the anti-digaonals were in reverse order).

Answer (score 1):

Short version:

If you preassign your `result` array, everything will be a lot faster.

```
result = zeros(1,knownLengthOfResultsArray); %# such as "numel(block)"
ct = 1;
for i=1:N
    tmp = nextPart(i);
    nTmp = length(tmp);
    result(ct:ct+nTmp-1) = tmp;
    ct = ct + nTmp;
end
```

Long version:

However, it may be even more efficient to rewrite your algorithm. See e.g. the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440641/transforming-a-matrix-into-a-vector-along-its-diagonals) (use `fliplr` on your array first), or [@gnovice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300606/concatmap-in-matlab/4300645#4300645).