# convert 1d to 2d matrix using zigzag ordering

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an 1D matrix in MATLAB that in created with best answer of mentioned question below, I would like to reorder it to first array:

[Matrix "Zigzag" Reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939/matrix-zigzag-reordering)

[image: zigzag layout pattern] 
Source: [Wikidpedia: Jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)

```
m = [69     9    75    46    23    16   100    83    92    54     8    45];

zigzag_writing(m, 4, 3)
```

ans=

```
69     9    16   100
75    23    83     8
46    92    54    45
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27078-zig-zag-scan/content/invzigzag.m

Comment: @Daniel Could you post it as an answer, so Developia can accept it? It will help other people find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the [`invzigzag`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27078-zig-zag-scan/content/invzigzag.m) at matlab file exchange.

```
>> invzigzag(m,3,4)

ans =

    69     9    16   100
    75    23    83     8
    46    92    54    45
```