# How to find ith item in zigzag ordering?

Tags: algorithm, math

A question last week defined the zig zag ordering on an n by m matrix and asked [how to list the elements in that order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939/matrix-zigzag-reordering).

[image]

My question is how to quickly find the ith item in the zigzag ordering? That is, without traversing the matrix (for large n and m that's much too slow).

For example with n=m=8 as in the picture and (x, y) describing (row, column)

```
f(0) = (0, 0)
f(1) = (0, 1)
f(2) = (1, 0)
f(3) = (2, 0)
f(4) = (1, 1)
...
f(63) = (7, 7)
```

Specific question: what is the ten billionth (1e10) item in the zigzag ordering of a million by million matrix?

Comment: Bounty to an answer with a correct solution to the 'million by a million' example. Extra credit for supporting non square matrices. Think before you code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Let's assume that the desired element is located in the upper half of the matrix. The length of the diagonals are `1, 2, 3 ..., n`.
2. Let's find the desired diagonal. It satisfies the following property:
   `sum(1, 2 ..., k) >= pos` but `sum(1, 2, ..., k - 1) < pos`. The sum of `1, 2, ..., k` is `k * (k + 1) / 2`. So we just need to find the smallest integer `k` such that `k * (k + 1) / 2 >= pos`. We can either use a binary search or solve this quadratic inequality explicitly.
3. When we know the `k`, we just need to find the `pos - (k - 1) * k / 2` element of this diagonal. We know where it starts and where we should move(up or down, depending on the parity of `k`), so we can find the desired cell using a simple formula.

This solution has an `O(1)` or an `O(log n)` time complexity(it depends on whether we use a binary search or solve the inequation explicitly in step 2).

If the desired element is located in the lower half of the matrix, we can solve this problem for a `pos' = n * n - pos + 1` and then use symmetry to get the solution to the original problem.

I used 1-based indexing in this solution, using 0-based indexing might require adding +1 or -1 somewhere, but the idea of the solution is the same.

If the matrix is rectangular, not square, we need to consider the fact the length of diagonals look this way: `1, 2, 3, ..., m, m, m, .., m, m - 1, ..., 1`(if `m <= n`) when we search for the `k`, so the sum becomes something like `k * (k + 1) / 2` if `k <= m` and `k * (k + 1) / 2 + m * (k - m)` otherwise.

Comment: Brilliant that's pretty much what I did. You explain it clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import math, random

def naive(n, m, ord, swap = False):
    dx = 1
    dy = -1
    if swap:
        dx, dy = dy, dx
    cur = [0, 0]
    for i in range(ord):
        cur[0] += dy
        cur[1] += dx
        if cur[0] < 0 or cur[1] < 0 or cur[0] >= n or cur[1] >= m:
            dx, dy = dy, dx

        if cur[0] >= n:
            cur[0] = n - 1
            cur[1] += 2
        if cur[1] >= m:
            cur[1] = m - 1
            cur[0] += 2
        if cur[0] < 0: cur[0] = 0
        if cur[1] < 0: cur[1] = 0


    return cur

def fast(n, m, ord, swap = False):
    if n < m:
        x, y = fast(m, n, ord, not swap)
        return [y, x]

    alt = n * m - ord - 1
    if alt < ord:
        x, y = fast(n, m, alt, swap if (n + m) % 2 == 0 else not swap)
        return [n - x - 1, m - y - 1]

    if ord < (m * (m + 1) / 2):
        diag = int((-1 + math.sqrt(1 + 8 * ord)) / 2)
        parity = (diag + (0 if swap else 1)) % 2
        within = ord - (diag * (diag + 1) / 2)
        if parity: return [diag - within, within]
        else: return [within, diag - within]
    else:
        ord -= (m * (m + 1) / 2)
        diag = int(ord / m)
        within = ord - diag * m
        diag += m
        parity = (diag + (0 if swap else 1)) % 2
        if not parity:
            within = m - within - 1
        return [diag - within, within]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1000):
        n = random.randint(3, 100)
        m = random.randint(3, 100)
        ord = random.randint(0, n * m - 1)
        swap = random.randint(0, 99) < 50
        na = naive(n, m, ord, swap)
        fa = fast(n, m, ord, swap)
        assert na == fa, "(%d, %d, %d, %s) ==> (%s), (%s)" % (n, m, ord, swap, na, fa)

    print fast(1000000, 1000000, 9999999999, False)
    print fast(1000000, 1000000, 10000000000, False)
```

So the 10-billionth element (the one with ordinal `9999999999`), and the 10-billion-first element (the one with ordinal `10^10`) are:

```
[20331, 121089]
[20330, 121090]
```

Answer (score 0):

## An analytical solution

In the general case, your matrix will be divided in 3 areas:

- an initial triangle **t1**
- a skewed part **mid** where diagonals have a constant length
- a final triangle **t2**

Let's call **p** the index of your diagonal run.
We want to define two functions **x(p)** and **y(p)** that give you the column and row of the **p**<sub>th</sub> cell.

### Initial triangle

Let's look at the initial triangular part **t1**, where each new diagonal is one unit longer than the preceding.

Now let's call **d** the index of the diagonal that holds the cell, and
**Sp = sum(d<sub>i</sub>)** for **i** in **[0..p-1]**

We have **p = Sp + k**, with **0 <=k <= d** and
**Sp = d(d+1)/2**

if we solve for **d**, it brings
**d²+d-2p = 0**, a quadratic equation where we retain only the positive root:
**d = (-1+sqrt(1+8*p))/2**

Now we want the highest integer value closest to **d**, which is **floor(d)**.

In the end, we have
**p = d + k** with **d = floor((-1+sqrt(1+8*p))/2)** and **k = p - d(d+1)/2**

Let's call
**o(d)** the function that equals **1** if **d** is **odd** and 0 otherwise, and
 **e(d)** the function that equals **1** if **d** is **even** and 0 otherwise.

We can compute **x(p)** and **y(p)** like so:

```
d = floor((-1+sqrt(1+8*p))/2)  
k = p - d(d+1)/2  
o = d % 2  
e = 1 - o
x = e*d + (o-e)*k  
y = o*d + (e-o)*k
```

> <sub>even and odd functions are used to try to salvage some clarity, but you can replace
>
>   **e(p)** with **1 - o(p)** and have slightly more efficient but less symetric formulaes for **x** and **y**</sub>.

### Middle part

let's consider the smallest matrix dimension **s**, i.e. **s = min (m,n)**.
The previous formulaes hold until **x** or **y** (whichever comes first) reaches the value **s**.

The upper bound of **p** such as **x(i) <= s and y(i) <= s** for all **i** in **[0..p]**
(i.e. the cell indexed by p is inside the initial triangle t1) is given by
**p<sub>t1</sub> = s(s+1)/2**.

For **p >= p<sub>t1</sub>**, diagonal length remains equal to **s** until we reach the second triangle **t2**.

when inside **mid**, we have:
**p = s(s+1)/2 + ds + k** with **k** in **[0..s[**.
which yields:
**d = floor ((p - s(s+1)/2)/s)**
**k = p - ds**

We can then use the same even/odd trick to compute **x(p)** and **y(p)**:

```
p -= s(s+1)/2
d = floor (p / s)
k = p - d*s
o = (d+s) % 2  
e = 1 - o
x = o*s + (e-o)*k
y = e*s + (o-e)*k
if (n > m)
    x += d+e
    y -= e
else
    y += d+o
    x -= o
```

### Final triangle

Using symetry, we can calculate **p<sub>t2</sub> = m*n - s(s+1)/2**

We now face nearly the same problem as for **t1**, except that the diagonal may run in the same direction as for **t1** ***or*** in the reverse direction (if **n+m** is odd).

Using symetry tricks, we can compute **x(p)** and **y(p)** like so:

```
        p = n*m -1 - p
        d = floor((-1+sqrt(1+8*p))/2)
        k = p - d*(d+1)/2
        o = (d+m+n) % 2  
        e = 1 - $o;
        x = n-1 - (o*d + (e-o)*k)
        y = m-1 - (e*d + (o-e)*k)
```

### Putting all together

Here is a sample c++ implementation.

- I used 64 bits integers out of sheer lazyness. Most could be replaced by 32 bits values.
- The computations could be made more effective by precomputing a few more coefficients.
- A good part of the code could be factorized, but I doubt it is worth the effort.

Since this is just a quick and dirty proof of concept, I did not optimize it.

```
#include <cstdio>    // printf
#include <algorithm> // min
using namespace std;

typedef long long tCoord;

void panic(const char * msg) 
{ 
    printf("PANIC: %s\n", msg);
    exit(-1);
}

struct tPoint {
    tCoord x, y;
    tPoint(tCoord x = 0, tCoord y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {}
    tPoint operator+(const tPoint & p) const { return{ x + p.x, y + p.y }; }
    bool operator!=(const tPoint & p) const { return x != p.x || y != p.y; }
};

class tMatrix {
    tCoord n, m; // dimensions
    tCoord s;    // smallest dimension
    tCoord pt1, pt2; // t1 / mid / t2 limits for p
public:
    tMatrix(tCoord n, tCoord m) : n(n), m(m)
    {
        s = min(n, m);
        pt1 = (s*(s + 1)) / 2;
        pt2 = n*m - pt1;
    }

    tPoint diagonal_cell(tCoord p)
    {
        tCoord x, y;

        if (p < pt1) // inside t1
        {
            tCoord d = (tCoord)floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * p)) / 2);
            tCoord k = p - (d*(d + 1)) / 2;
            tCoord o = d % 2;
            tCoord e = 1 - o;
            x = o*d + (e - o)*k;
            y = e*d + (o - e)*k;
        }
        else if (p < pt2) // inside mid
        {
            p -= pt1;
            tCoord d = (tCoord)floor(p / s);
            tCoord k = p - d*s;
            tCoord o = (d + s) % 2;
            tCoord e = 1 - o;
            x = o*s + (e - o)*k;
            y = e*s + (o - e)*k;
            if (m > n) // vertical matrix
            {
                x -= o;
                y += d + o;
            }
            else // horizontal matrix
            {
                x += d + e;
                y -= e;
            }
        }
        else // inside t2
        {
            p = n * m - 1 - p;
            tCoord d = (tCoord)floor((-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * p)) / 2);
            tCoord k = p - (d*(d + 1)) / 2;
            tCoord o = (d + m + n) % 2;
            tCoord e = 1 - o;
            x = n - 1 - (o*d + (e - o)*k);
            y = m - 1 - (e*d + (o - e)*k);
        }

        return{ x, y };
    }

    void check(void)
    {
        tPoint move[4] = { { 1, 0 }, { -1, 1 }, { 1, -1 }, { 0, 1 } };
        tPoint pos;
        tCoord dir = 0;
        for (tCoord p = 0; p != n * m ; p++)
        {
            tPoint dc = diagonal_cell(p);
            if (pos != dc) panic("zot!");

            pos = pos + move[dir];
            if (dir == 0)
            {
                if (pos.y == m - 1) dir = 2;
                else dir = 1;
            }
            else if (dir == 3)
            {
                if (pos.x == n - 1) dir = 1;
                else dir = 2;
            }
            else if (dir == 1)
            {
                if (pos.y == m - 1) dir = 0;
                else if (pos.x == 0) dir = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                if (pos.x == n - 1) dir = 3;
                else if (pos.y == 0) dir = 0;
            }
        }

    }
};

void main(void)
{
    const tPoint dim[] = { { 10, 10 }, { 11, 11 }, { 10, 30 }, { 30, 10 }, { 10, 31 }, { 31, 10 }, { 11, 31 }, { 31, 11 } };
    for (tPoint d : dim)
    {
        printf("Checking a %lldx%lld matrix...", d.x, d.y);
        tMatrix(d.x, d.y).check();
        printf("done\n");
    }
    tCoord p = 10000000000;
    tMatrix matrix(1000000, 1000000);
    tPoint cell = matrix.diagonal_cell(p);
    printf("Coordinates of %lldth cell: (%lld,%lld)\n", p, cell.x, cell.y);
}
```

Results are checked against "manual" sweep of the matrix.
This "manual" sweep is a ugly hack that won't work for a one-row or one-column matrix, though `diagonal_cell()` *does* work on any matrix (the "diagonal" sweep becomes linear in that case).

The coordinates found for the 10.000.000.000th cell of a 1.000.000x1.000.000 matrix seem consistent, since the diagonal **d** on which the cell stands is about sqrt(2*1e10), approx. 141421, and the sum of cell coordinates is about equal to **d** (121090+20330 = 141420). Besides, it is also what the two other posters report.

I would say there is a good chance this lump of obfuscated code actually produces an O(1) solution to your problem.