# How to create a zigzag matrix in Octave?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have to write a function in Octave that creates a zigzag matrix of order `n`, where `n` is given as an input parameter of the function. The function will have the following header:

```
function R = zig-zag(n)
```

For example: `zig-zag(5)` should generate a matrix like this:

```
0   1   5   6  14
2   4   7  13  15
3   8  12  16  21
9  11  17  20  22
10 18  19  23  24
```

How can I write this as easy as possible in Octave?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix "Zigzag" Reordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939/matrix-zigzag-reordering)

Comment: What have you done to solve this? Have you tried anything or you want someone to do it for you?