# Column Vector to Transposed Triangular Matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, triangular

If I have a vector

```
A = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
```

Is there any way to convert this to a matrix

```
[0   2   5   9   14 
 1   4   8   13  0
 3   7   12  0   0
 6   11  0   0   0
 10  0   0   0   0 ]
```

For vector A of length 2016.

So far:

```
n = 63;
B = triu(true(n));
C = zeros(n);
C(B) = A;
```

Looks to be on the right line.

Then to try and create vector D whereby each column is the diagonal of matrix C...

```
D = zeros(n);

for i = 1:n;
    D(:,i) = diag(C,i-1);
end
```

But on the second iteration the length of the diagonal does not fill an entire column (as expected and desired) and I get a dimension mismatch error.

Comment: So the last 4 elements become the first row, next-last 3 elements become the second row (with zero padding), next-last 2 elements become the third row (with zero padding) and so on?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear what I am after... sorry if it still isn't explained well! In reality i need to repeat this pattern for a matrix A of length 2016.

Comment: It would help if you gave the actual result matrix with whatever filler values you want to use (or maybe you actually want a cell array?). The syntax you're showing is not legal in MATLAB.

Comment: You cannot have a **matrix** with rows with different numbers of columns. You can only do that with a **cell array**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix "Zigzag" Reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024939/matrix-zigzag-reordering)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe as indicated. The diagonals are all upward here

Comment: It looks very similar to the reverse of the zigzag reordering! And my apologies it can be a matrix with all empty elements assigned as zeros.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, I guess they're all going the same direction. It was kinda hard to see until Wolfie's edit.

Comment: Ok I have continued on with the solution provided earlier but hit another small snag... Im so sorry about my earlier errors. I do not have extensive experience with matlab and this is the first time posting on stackoverflow!

Comment: Hopefully it is much more clear what I am trying to achieve now?

Comment: Will `A` always fit that way in the matrix? That is, will its length always be a triangular number?

Comment: Yes in my case A has length 2016 and fits into a 63x63 matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that the length of `A` is a triangular number, so that `A` can fit in half a square matrix including the diagonal:

```
N = (sqrt(numel(A)*8+1)-1)/2;
t = hankel(1:N);
t(t==0) = inf;
[~, ind]= sort(t(:));
ind = ind(1:numel(A));
result = zeros(N);
result(ind) = A;
```

Comment: Another solution!

Answer (score 4):

Here's one with some help from [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) -

```
function out = zigzag_upward(A, n)
% If n is needed to be computed : n = floor(sqrt(numel(A)*2))
r = 1:n;
valid_mask = bsxfun(@le, r,r(end:-1:1)');
all_vals = cumsum([(cumsum(0:n-1)+1)' bsxfun(@plus,[0:n-1]',2:n)],2);
all_vals(all_vals > numel(A)) = 1;
out = valid_mask .* A(all_vals);
```

Sample run -

```
>> A = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]+20;
>> zigzag_upward(A, 5)
ans =
    20    22    25    29    34
    21    24    28    33     0
    23    27    32     0     0
    26    31     0     0     0
    30     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The solution I needed was transpose(out)  but this was probably due to my terrible explanations!

Comment: I gave you +1 inspite of that `'`:-P Would you change it to `.'`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Hah, well all those are range arrays, so should be safe! :D It was intentional BTW ;)

Comment: @LuisMendo Keep it for the bsxfun! ;)